# ¿Cómo saber el tipo de un Document si cambio el prototipo y constructor?

Tags: javascript, variables, consola, google-chrome

Hago una variable de tipo `Document` en *JavaScript* mediante `new Document()`, y quisiera hacer que detecte si el tipo es `Document` o no. ¿Es posible hacer esto?

```
var documento = new Document()
```

Parece fácil, mi intento fue el siguiente:

```
documento.toString()==="[object Document]"
```

Con esto a mi parecer estaba solucionado, pero yo puedo hacer:

```
var documento = "[object Document]"
```

Si quiero hacer la comprobación anterior, me va a dar `true`, pero ahora `documento` es de tipo *String*, ya no es `Document`.

Puedo mirar el `constructor`, lo siguiente devuelve `true`:

```
documento.constructor===Document
```

Es posible eliminar `Document`. ¿Por qué el navegador permite hacer esto?

```
delete Document
```

Si lo intento, la variable `documento` seguirá siendo de tipo `Document`, pero ya no tengo manera de comprobarlo. Haciendo esto, al parecer es imposible recuperar el `Document` eliminado, a no ser que esté perteneciendo a alguna variable desconocida.

Entonces no voy a borrarlo, pero puedo ir más lejos, cambiando su `__proto__` y su `constructor` por `Array`.

```
documento.__proto__ = Array()
documento.constructor = Array()
```

Para mi sorpresa, en la consola de mi navegador, que es *Chromium* sigo viendo que el resultado de la variable es `#document`.

Si convierto la variable a string mediante `JSON.stringify` me muestra su `location`.

```
JSON.stringify(documento)
```

Si intento eliminar su propiedad `location` me devuelve `false`. Eso es buen indicio que es de tipo `Document`, ya que no es posible instanciar un `Location` directamente, es decir, un `Location` solo pertenece a `Document`.

```
delete documento.location // Devuelve false
```

Sabiendo todo esto, puedo crear un objeto desde cero y hacer que se parezca a un `Document` pero sin serlo realmente. Puedo hacer que sea imposible eliminar `location`, y que al hacer `toString()` muestre `[object Document]`:

```
var documento = {location: null}
documento.__proto__ = new Document()

Object.defineProperty(documento,"location",{
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false
})
Object.defineProperty(documento,"constructor",{
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    value: Document
})
Object.defineProperty(documento,"toString",{
    writable: true,
    value: x=>"[object Document]",
    enumerable: false
})
```

Lo que no logro hacer es que se muestre `#document`. En cambio, muestra lo siguiente:

```
Document {location: null, constructor: ƒ, toString: ƒ}
```

Aunque se ve que son diferentes, no conozco ningún método en *JavaScript* para comprobar que son diferentes.

[image: Diferencia entre un Document y su simulación]

Estoy en *Linux* con el navegador *Chromium*, y la versión es la siguiente:

> *Versión 80.0.3987.163 (Build oficial) snap (64 bits)*

Dejo otra captura de pantalla, pueden comprobarlo ustedes mismos.

[image: Tratando de acceder a Document]

Entonces me surgen muchas preguntas:

- ¿Esto es un *bug* del navegador? y si es así, ¿Está reportado? ¿Puede verse en el código fuente?
- Cuando la consola muestra `#document`, ¿Lo que muestra puede obtenerse desde alguna propiedad de la variable `documento`?
- ¿Es posible guardar la salida de la consola en una variable?
- ¿Por qué el tipo sigue siendo `#document` si ya le cambié su `__proto__` y su `constructor`?

Comment: Decia... @ArtEze si has probado a usar `getProprotypeOf` te dejo el enlace a la documentación oficial en español: [https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/getPrototypeOf) 
p.d. gracias @Ruben

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia No lo había probado, pero entré a verlo, y si le cambio el prototipo me muestra _`> []`_, y además me sucede algo extraño, mientras estoy escribiendo el nombre de la variable `documento`, aparece la vista previa del resultado como `Array` en color violeta transparente, y cuando presiono la tecla `Entrar` se muestra como `#document`. Dejo una captura de pantalla. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLz43.png

Comment: @Rubén Más arriba yo había mencionado que estoy en _Chromium_, acabo de editar la pregunta aclarando eso junto a la versión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que aparece en el proyecto *DevTools* es en verdad un *bug* del *Eager Evaluation*. Esta característica se puede desactivar o volver a activar desde la tuerca en la consola.

[image: Bug de Chromium]

Para saber el tipo se tiene que usar [`Object.getProprotypeOf(document)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/getPrototypeOf).

El tipo real de un *Document* al cambiar el `__proto__` es un un *Array*, y el hecho de que no se pueda borrar la propiedad `location`, no significa que siga siendo un *Document*. En realidad solamente es una propiedad constante dentro de un objeto.

Cambiar el prototipo de una instancia de un *Document* es bastante peligroso, ya que además, cambia el prototipo de `document`, y cualquier instancia de `Document`. Esto hace que cualquier evento que se esté ejecutando sobre el *DOM* deje de funcionar.

Por ejemplo, algo que me sucedió fue que al cambiar el `__proto__`, había un `setInterval` en *GitHub*, que intentaba acceder a *Google Analytics* usando el método `querySelector`, y al cambiar el `__proto__` a un array generaba decenas de errores por segundo en la consola, saturando la memoria y el procesador (de todos modos mi computadora es del año 2001), y la única solución para salir de este problema fue cerrando el navegador cuanto antes.